# Running Java Class which calls class from another folder

Tags: java

I have in one folder /projects/A/Test.java
with the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void t() {

        System.out.println("Hey");

    }

}
```

and in folder#2 /projects/
with the following code:

```
public class Test2 {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        t.t();

    }

}
```

I compile the first one with: javac Test.java
I compile the second one with javac Test2.java -cp ./A

Now when I try to run Test2: java Test2, I receive an error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test`

How can I run Test2, which calls Test from a subfolder?

Answer (score 2):

If your classes are in different places you have to set the classpath when running, just like when you compile.

```
java -cp .:./A Test2                           # On Unix use :, on Windows ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in class test you had to specify package in the beginning of the file.

```
package A;
```

And then import it in your Test2 class.

```
import A.Test
```

you don't have to set package and import Test if both locations project and project/A are in your classpath